# Bash script error. What is wrong with this script?

Tags: bash

I'm new at `bash` script writing and I have this error. I have looked everywhere to find an answer with no success. What is wrong with this script?

```
#!/bin/bash 

exec >> /Users/k_herriage/bin/post-gererate.out 2>&1
date
set -x

mynewfile="~/bin/convert_tst.txt"

myfile=fopen($mynewfile,'w+' );
#echo $myfile

    fwrite($myfile, "testing");
    fclose($myfile);

exit (0)


line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 7:`myfile = fopen ( '~/bin/convert_tst.txt','w' );'
```

Comment: Looks like your mixing shell and Perl syntax. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Few points:

- Calling a function in bash does not require parens, it is syntactically equivalent to a command:

  ```
  do_something arg1 arg2 arg3
  ```
- There is no need to do open-append-close sequence in bash, it is perfectly doable with a single command:

  ```
  echo "testing" >> $mynewfile; ##
  ```

  `>>` means "append", where if it was `>`, it would mean "overwrite" or "discard content". (Both will create the file if it didn't exist.)